# HERE Maps API for Javascript : how to get boundaries longitude and latitude from current zoom Visible Map

Tags: javascript, geolocation, maps, here-api, heremaps

I am using the HERE Maps API for Javascript for the webpage: how to get boundaries longitude and latitude from current zoom Visible Map.

When the map display on the webpage is a rectangle shape, what is the method to get 4 boundaries points longitude and latitude in the visible area of Here maps?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.map.ViewModel.html#getLookAtData), the bounds object in getLookAtData method for ViewModel is a bounding box in 2D map and a polygon in 3D map. Therefore:

```js
bb = map.getViewModel().getLookAtData().bounds.getBoundingBox();

bb.getTop(); 
bb.getLeft(); 
bb.getBottom(); 
bb.getRight();

// or 
bb.getTopLeft();
bb.getBottomRight();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much more complicated than it should be:

```
map.getViewModel().getLookAtData().bounds.getBoundingBox()
```

You'll get an object like that:

```
Object {
    ba: 12.375232332750691,
    ga: 12.379826130043003,
    ja: 51.33821375191854,
    ka: 51.337248429832854,
    b: null, a: null, c: null
}
```